# Safari restored a private browsing session after my Mac crashed

Tags: safari, macos, privacy

I know where Safari keeps cache information, but my computer froze, and I had to reboot it forcibly.

Prior to the freeze, I was using Safari with private browsing enabled (i.e. I was using a private window). However, after the reboot Safari completely restored the previous session. I did not expect this as I had been using it in private mode.

**Where is Safari storing this information?** 
I am also wondering if it is safe to delete `~/Library/Safari`?

My bookmarks are in iCloud, and I don't know if I can assume that directory is a privacy concern.

Comment: Interesting question. Hope we find out more.